# How to get more space on /boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have tried sudo apt-get clean and bleachbit.
I know that my computer has plenty of free space.
When I try to get an update it says /boot doesnt have enough free space.
Is there any way I can just take some free space and give it to /boot?
Sorry if this is a dumb question.

```
jack@jack-HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC:~$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  684G   14G  636G   3% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        335M  1.5M  334M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         1.7G  256K  1.7G   1% /run/shm
none                         100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2                    237M  179M   46M  80% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
```

It worked thanks riotejas

Comment: You want `apt-get autoremove` not clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do an ls -l of /boot and see what images you have.  run `apt-get purge` to remove the old pkgs, e.g., if I have .38 and .37 kernels, remove the .37 version:

```
russell@ff:~$ ll /boot
total 60913
<snip>
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20255298 Oct 20 16:16 initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20253276 Nov  6 19:50 initrd.img-3.13.0-38-generic
<snip>
```

Then remove the .37 version prefacing with 'linux-image-'

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic
```